# How do I append odd numbers to folder name using Windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I used a batch script that I found on this site to create a directory of 50 states with roughly 3000 subdirectories for counties.

Unfortunately, the files I will be copying in to the directory are in FIPS code.  FIPS code is just a series of odd numbers, starting with 001, that apply to the alphabetical listing of the counties, by state.  As an example, Alabama starts with Autauga county as the first alphabetical county with a FIPS code of 001, second county is Baldwin with FIPS code 003,etc.... and ends with Winston County with a FIPS code of 133.  So I need to append the FIPS code 3 digit number to the county folder name, i.e Autauga_001.   I think its as simple as adding n+=2 but it needs to start at 001?

I am very green to writing batch files.  Have spent hours trying to piecemeal similar code listed on this site to suit my needs but to no avail.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and remove the `echo` command, if the output is OK:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem set root to the subfolder, where the 50 state folders are inside
set "root=states"

pushd "%root%"
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    set /a counter=1001
    for /d %%j in ("%%~fi\*") do (
        set "newname=%%~nj_!counter:~-3!%%~xj"
        echo rename "%%~fj" "!newname!"
        set /a counter+=2
    )
)
popd
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I tried the above code, it runs the command line though the entire directory (called "stateimagery"), but does not add the numbers to the folder names.  Changed root = states to root=stateimagery.  Anything else I need change?  The directory looks like this for alabama:  stateimagery\alabama\Autauga_Alabama.   I need it to look like stateimagery\alabama\Autauga_Alabama_001.

Comment: If you see the new names are OK, remove the `echo` command (before `rename`) from the script.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see your comment.   The folders are not getting renamed.  They are the same?  Thanks

Comment: Just tried it again with echo removed.  I end up with a !newname! folder for the first county folder in each state.  Any ideas

Comment: Genius!!!!  It worked.  I removed first line of echo and did not put it back in.  Sorry.   Thank you Endoro.  You have just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions (websites, books, blogs) for a newbie that wants to learn more about windows batch commands?  Thanks again.

Comment: Usenet: **alt.msdos.batch.nt** is a good place to find snippets of code and people to discuss them with.